# how to show/hide input type:text when button is click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**reply button**

```
<div id="replybutton" class="btn4 like" style="margin-top:-25px;margin-left:-10px;">
   <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span> 
</div>
```

**input field**

```
<div  class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
    <input type="text"  id="reply" class="form-control pull-right" style="width:88%;height:25px;margin-top:-10px;" placeholder="Write a reply..." />
</div>
```

so here what im trying to make is when i reload the page the input field should be hidden and when i click the reply button it will show.. and when i click it again it will hide.. i tried using `toggle()` on jquery it works but the problem is if i reload the page the button is visible which is not the right thing.. i even tried to use `.show()` and `.hide()` but it seems im missing something so it doesn't work on my end. is there any way i can make it happens that when i reload the page the input field should be hidden..

Comment: use css display:none or use cookie, if cookie set then don't show else show.

Comment: `$(function () { 
    $('#reply').hide();
});`

`$( "#replyb" ).on('click', function() {
   $( "#reply" ).toggle();
});`

Comment: use css display:none, when page load its hide....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code snippet:

Remember the **initial state should be hidden** `style="display:none;"`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="replybutton" class="btn4 like">
<span class="btn reply" id="replyb" onClick="$('#reply').toggle();">Reply</span> 
</div>

    <input type="text"  id="reply" class="form-control pull-right"  placeholder="Write a reply..." style="display:none;"/>
```

You can also use the click listener approach:

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="replybutton" class="btn4 like">
    <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span> 
    </div>
        <input type="text"  id="reply" class="form-control pull-right"  placeholder="Write a reply..." style="display:none;"/>
        
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#replyb').click(function(){
    $('#reply').toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#replybutton').click(function() {
  $('#reply').toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="replybutton" class="btn4 like" style="">
  <span class="btn reply" id="replyb">Reply</span>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background:#eff9c7;">
  <input type="text" id="reply" class="form-control pull-right" style="width:88%;height:25px;margin-top:0px;" placeholder="Write a reply..." hidden />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`style='visibility:hidden'` or `style='display:none`'.

```
$('#replyb').click(function() {
  $('#reply').toggle()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#replyb').click(function(){
    $('#reply').toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```